# Sort nodes of a XML file

Tags: xslt, sorting

Sorting is giving me a hard time.

I need help with an small example, so that I can understand xsl:sort better.

My xml data looks as followed:

```
<NewTerms>
  <newTerm>Zebra</newTerm>
  <newTerm>Horse</newTerm>
  <newTerm>Cat</newTerm>
  <newTerm>Lion</newTerm>
  <newTerm>Jaguar</newTerm>
  <newTerm>Cheetah</newTerm>
  <newTerm>Deer</newTerm>
  <newTerm>Buffalo</newTerm>
  <newTerm>Dog</newTerm>
</NewTerms>
```

and I just simply want to sort them alphabetically from a xsl sheet. The xsl that i have written (& which is not working) is as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="NewTerms">

      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="newTerm"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>

  </xsl:template>  
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am very sure that I haven't understood how xsl:sort function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want a valid XML structure as output again because in your `<xsl:output>` the method is "XML".
You could try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
version="1.0">
    
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gives this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NewTerms>
<newTerm>Buffalo</newTerm>
<newTerm>Cat</newTerm>
<newTerm>Cheetah</newTerm>
<newTerm>Deer</newTerm>
<newTerm>Dog</newTerm>
<newTerm>Horse</newTerm>
<newTerm>Jaguar</newTerm>
<newTerm>Lion</newTerm>
<newTerm>Zebra</newTerm>
</NewTerms>
```

You could also look at the definition of sort,e.g.:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp
http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#sorting

Comment: Thank you very very much ... sometimes having a concrete example helps to understand a concept more than reading the theory .... So, Thank you again :) ... and you're right, am working on a .xml output. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Could you please explain me why we should use "@*|node()" ... cause i was under the impression that I should directly name the nodes' name that I am wanting to sort. Ofcourse I am wrong, but would like to know why?

Comment: @Jasmin: All you do is copy the whole XML structure and just adding the xsl:sort element. This copying mechanism is called "Identity Transform". Please have a look at: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying It is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <xsl:template match="NewTerms">
>  <xsl:apply-templates>
>   <xsl:sort select="newTerm"/>
>  </xsl:apply-templates>
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> I am very sure that I haven't
>   understood how xsl:sort function

You are right. From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#sorting

> `xsl:sort` has a `select` attribute
>   whose value is an expression. **For each
>   node to be processed, the expression
>   is evaluated with that node as the
>   current node and with the complete
>   list of nodes being processed in
>   unsorted order as the current node
>   list.**<sup>*</sup> The resulting object is
>   converted to a string as if by a call
>   to the `string` function; this
>   string is used as the sort key for
>   that node. The default value of the
>   `select` attribute is `.`, which will
>   cause the string-value of the current
>   node to be used as the sort key.

<sup>* Emphasis mine.</sup>

You want:

```
<xsl:template match="NewTerms">
 <xsl:apply-templates>
  <xsl:sort/>
 </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your exact explanation. I just provided a workaround to the original code.